# given two points find the slope- Python class

Tags: python, geometry

I am new to python and I am trying to figure out why this code won't work.

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def slope_from_origin (self,p1,p2):
      slope=((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x))
      return Point(slope)

  def __str__ (self):
      return str(slope)

p=Point(6,7)
q=Point(3,4)
print(p.slope_from_origin(q))
```

What should I change to make this code work? Thanks.

Comment: You defined your `slope_from_origin` method with two arguments: `p1` and `p2`. When you call it in your last line of code, you only pass one argument: `q`. Why would you think that'd work :}?

Comment: Rafael has got the main part, but you're also returning a Point object from a function that should likely just return the slope itself. (In fact you're trying to create a Point object with one value which would fail here)

Comment: You're also trying to construct a `Point` with only one argument when the constructor takes two…and referencing a `slope` variable that hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is a bit mixed up:

`slope_from_origin` is the slope that a line segment passing through the origin `Point(0, 0)`, and the given point makes.

`slope_between_two_points` is the slope that a line segment passing through the two given points makes.

`slope` is a scalar, you are trying to construct a `Point` with it, and return it

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def slope_between_two_points(self, p1=Point(0, 0)):  # uses default argument to define the origin
        if p1.x - self.x == 0:
            return float('inf')   # prevent dividing by zero when slope is infinite
       return (p1.y - self.y) / (p1.x - self.x)

    def slope_from_origin(self):
        return self.slope_between_two_points()

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(slope)

p = Point(6, 7)
q = Point(3, 4)
print(p.slope_between_two_points(q), p.slope_from_origin(), q.slope_from_origin())
```